# OWASP CSRFGuard JavaScript was included from within an unauthorized domain

Tags: security, cross-site

We use Owasp.CsrfGuard.js in  webapp project and got error OWASP CSRFGuard JavaScript was included from within an unauthorized domain!

One of the reason I have identified that, webapp is accessed using third party login application (Compass) and domain name of server where compass is installed is different from domain name of our webapp application. There is no configuration in compass other then url of webapp.

Not sure what could be the solution for this.